# I cant connect with my socketio client to socketio server(both python) when executing with double click on file but in vs code i can connect

Tags: python, http, sockets, https, socket.io

Server

```py
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='eventlet' ) # ping_timeout=60
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen((local ip of other device, 5050)), app)
"just a small version of the code"
```

Client

```py
sio.connect('http://' + str(local ip of serer) + ':' + str(5050))
```

1. Server(Vscode run File) + Client(Vscode run File ): Works
2. Server(Double Click on File) + Client(Vscode run File ): Works
3. Serer() + Client(Double Click on File ): Doesnt work

I got this Error when trying 3:

```
  File "C:\Users\juliu\Vision\Client\app.py", line 228, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\juliu\Vision\Client\app.py", line 37, in start
    sio.connect('http://' + str(host) + ':' + str(port))
  File "C:\Users\juliu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 338, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='local ip of lient', port=5050): Max retries exceeded with url: /socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4&t=1659296717.3303626 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000299A0D11660>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```